# Unity style named service registration in .net core injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm trying to have two types of registrations for the same service (`ServiceA`). I want one to be `scoped` (one instance per client request) and another, `transient` (a new instance each time the resolver is requested to provide an instance).

This is so when a client makes a request, I don't have multiple instances of `ServiceA` floating around when passing one around would do the job, but I also need to be able to spin one instance on demand when I ask the resolver to resolve an instance of a `BackgroundJobService` instance (which depends on a NEW instance of `ServiceA` because the scoped instance is disposed as soon as the request ends).

In Unity, you can do something like:

```
//this will spin a new instance
container.RegisterType<DataProvider>("ForBackgroundJobs", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
//this will return the same instance when resolved in the context of a request
container.RegisterType<DataProvider>(new Unity.AspNet.Mvc.PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

And when resolving

```
var service = container.Resolve<DataProvider>("ForBackgroundJobs"); // a new instance, each time this is called...
var service = container.Resolve<DataProvider>(); //same instance every time this is callede within the request.
```

Is there any way to do something like that with .NET Core's service provider ?

Comment: Looks like you're referring named registrations. The MS.DI extensions don't support that, though you can override the default provider with a provider of your choosing if you prefer. ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#default-service-container-replacement

However, if your clients are registered as scoped, then the transient dependencies will only be injected once per lifecycle of the client (scoped), regardless of their own registrations. (i.e. can you register the `DataProvider` as transient and control consumer lifes?)

Comment: You can't do this exactly like this. What you can do is add a parameter to your service that can be used in your constructors to differentiate between and choose the implementations. When you register multiple implementations from the same interface, they are injected into your classes as an IEnumerable, which you can choose from to select your service. Feels like a code smell though. A better solution would probably be to create a separate implementation of your interface for scoped vs transient lifespans. You may have some duplication but it will keep your DI much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something similar with little hack.

Let's have two interfaces that are implemented from our class IScoped and ITranscient with same methods.
Our class should implement both interfaces.
Register the class as transient with one interface and scoped with another.
Something like that:

> ```
> public class TestClass: IScoped, ITrancient
> {
>     public string GetString() => "Test string";
> }
> ```

```
public interface IScoped
{
    string GetString();
}

public interface ITrancient
{
    string GetString();
}
```

in configure service add:

```
.AddScoped<IScoped, TestClass>()
.AddTransient<ITrancient, TestClass>()
```

than you can access the class by desired interface
like 
     ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService() or register DI in constructor